# react-admin pass props Main->layout->appBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I have a react-admin app to manage users. Now I need to access some props in the custom header (appBar) that I created, but can't figure out how to get those accessible there.

Here some of the code.

**Main.js**

```
class Main extends React.Component
{

  render()
  {
    // const { }   = this.state;
    const { t } = this.props;
    const _this = this;

    return (
      <Admin dataProvider={dataProvider} {..._this.props.props} layout={CustomLayout}>
        <Resource name="users"
                  list={<UserList {..._this.props.props} />}
                  edit={<UserEdit {..._this.props.props} />}
                  create={<UserCreate {..._this.props.props} />}
        />
      </Admin>
    );
  }
}

export default Main;
```

**From above code `CustomLayout`**

```
const CustomLayout = (props) => <Layout
  {...props}
  appBar={Header}
  sidebar={Sidebar}
/>;

export default CustomLayout;
```

**From above code `Header`**

```
class Header extends React.Component {


  // ---> Lifecycle functions <---

  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);

    // Here I need to access props... 
    
    this.selectCustomer = this.selectCustomer.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      selectedCustomerId: this.props.selectedCustomerId,
    };
  }


    return (
      <div>...</div>
    );
  }
}


export default Header;
```

How do I get props from **Main -> CustomLayout -> Header**? If in `CustomLayout.js` I change `appBar={Header}` to `appBar={<Header {...props} />}`, I get `Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

I guess it needs to be the component-name. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preferred way here would be to use React functional components instead of classes and React.createContext() / [React.useContext()](https://react.dev/reference/react/useContext).

```
import { createContext, useState } from 'react'
export const MyContext = createContext(0)
...   
const App = () => {       
  const [customerId, setCustomerId] = useState(123)

  return (
        <MyContext.Provider value={customerId} >
          <Admin ...>
          ...
          </Admin>
        </MyContext.Provider>      
  )
}
...

import { useContext } from 'react'
import { AppBar } from 'react-admin'
import { MyContext } from 'App'
...
const CustomAppBar = (props: any) => {
  const value = useContext(MyContext)
  console.log('CustomAppBar, customerId:', value)

  return (<AppBar color="primary" {...props} >
      <TitlePortal />
      <div>{ 'ID:' + value }</div>
    </AppBar>)
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate how I would do that? Does that work together with react-admin?

Comment: Thanks for the code example. I got it working!